# how do i make sure items in a list is sequential ?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

good day !

I would like to ask if i have a list of items say 1,2,3,4,5..
then i insert a replace value'3' to '7' which will prompt me an error cos the list is not sequential.

```
List<Domain> items = new ArrayList<Domain>();
```

Comment: Why not write a method that checks whether the item you're about to insert is bigger than its predecessor, and smaller than its successor?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ArrayList, set and add methods to check whether the item set/added is valid and throw an IllegalArgumentException if it isn't.

Why not have a collection which is always sorted.

```
SortedSet<Domain> items = new TreeSet<Domain>();
```

This way, your added item will always be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the ArrayList and override `add()` & `addAll()` method,

Or Simple use `Comparator` & `TreeSet`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an exception when you replace an element, like you describe, the best way is to extend or wrap a list and override the add methods.

If all you really want is a sorted list, use one of the [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7, try using:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html